# I have a ListView where I add and delete ListElements. When I delete a ListElement (row), is there a way to animate the movement of the lower items?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

In my ListView, I have an add button which appends a ListElement to the end of the ListView. Each ListElement has a delete button within its row, and when it is clicked, I animate it going away, but I also want to animate any items below when the move up.

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    delegate: myListViewDelegate
    model: myListModel
    anchors.fill: parent
}

ListModel {
    id: myListModel
}

Component {
    id: myListViewDelegate
    Item {
        id: rowContainer
        height: 40
        width: myListView.width

        Text {
            id: labelText

            text: label

            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }

        CustomButton {
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                rightMargin: 8
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            width: 32
            height: width
            buttonRadius: width/2
            iconSource: "qrc:/image/Delete.png"

            onReleased: deleteRowAnimation.start()
        }

        ParallelAnimation {
            id: deleteRowAnimation
            SmoothedAnimation {velocity: 300; target: rowContainer; properties: "x"; to: -rowContainer.width}

            onRunningChanged: if(!running) deleteRow(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Later in the code..

```
function deleteRow(index) {
    myListModel.remove(index)
}
```

I am able to animate the row leaving (being deleted), but if there are rows below it, they jump up to fill the spot where the row was deleted. I would like this to be a smooth, animated transition.

Comment: did you read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how it works:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: qsTr('Frameless')
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel{
            ListElement {text: "111111"}
            ListElement {text: "222222"}
            ListElement {text: "333333"}
            ListElement {text: "444444"}
            ListElement {text: "555555"}
            ListElement {text: "666666"}
            ListElement {text: "777777"}
            ListElement {text: "888888"}
        }
        delegate: Text {
            id: name
            text: qsTr(modelData)
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "red"
                opacity: 0.4
            }
        }
        displaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { property: "y" duration: 200 }
        }
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Esc"
        onActivated: view.model.remove(2)
    }
}
```

On Escape the 3rd element element is being removed and that is triggering the rest of the list to move up.
Possibilities of this are endless. Have fun!

Comment: This is just an example, not to be used as a solution. Obviously I didn't take care of index removal so this will stop working after pulling out 6 items.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! While the animation is displayed perfectly, I still get a "ReferenceError: name is not defined" ("name" being the id in your example). If I remove the "to: y - name.height;" altogether, the animation still works as intended. So the whole line is "NumberAnimation { property: "y"; duration: 200 }"